# How to add/display event using calendar_view

Tags: flutter, dart, package, calendar

I'm using the calendar_view package to display events on dates. I have read the documentation but I am still confused how to display events on MonthView() Widget

```
CalendarControllerProvider(
    controller: EventController(),
    child: MaterialApp(
        // Your initialization for material app.
    ),
)
//reste of code

 List<CalendarEventData> events = [
            CalendarEventData(
                title: "title to display", date: DateTime(2023, 06, 2), 
event: "or this event to display")];

MonthView(             
controller: EventController(),
              // to provide custom UI for month cells.
cellBuilder: (date, events, isToday, isInMonth) {
                // Return your widget to display as month cell.
                return Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Text(date.day.toString()),
                    Text("I want to display here event based on date")
                  ],
                );
              },
              minMonth: DateTime(2020),
              maxMonth: DateTime(2023),
              initialMonth: DateTime(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month),
              onPageChange: (date, pageIndex) => print("$date, $pageIndex"),
              onCellTap: (events, date) {
                // here we must add event
              },
              startDay: WeekDays.sunday, // To change the first day of the week.
              // This callback will only work if cellBuilder is null.
            ),
```

Answer (score 1):

after many tries I got solution with myself maybe someone can find it helpful...
the problem was in how to display events in the cells

```
// First we add event to controller
 final event = CalendarEventData(
          date: DateTime(2023, 7, 07),
          title: 'Duplicate',
        );
        controller.add(event);

// second step to display the event in cellbuilder
MonthView(
 cellBuilder: (date, events, isToday, isInMonth) {
              // Return your widget to display as month cell.
              if (events.isNotEmpty) {
                // Display the first event's title in the cell.
                 // at place 0 you can index it
                    return Text(events[0].title),
              } else {
                // No events, return an empty container.
                return Container();
              }
                 //Rest of code

            },),
```

Answer (score 0):

calendar_view library has an controller (EventController). You can create an instance of this controller:

```
 final EventController controller = EventController();
```

and using this controller in **MonthView**

```
MonthView(
  controller:controller ,
);
```

you can add events in this controller:

```
 controller.addAll(<CalendarEventData>[ ]);
```

Comment: not work i tried : 
controller.addAll(<CalendarEventData>[
          CalendarEventData(
            date: DateTime(2023, 6, 2),
            event: "Event 1",
            title: 'message',
          )
        ]);
and nothing display